# How do I perform a where query on an enum attribute with a string rather than the ordinal value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

So I have a model that has an enum value like so:

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum request_status: { pending: 0, accepted: 1, rejected: 2, removed: 3 }
end
```

But, I have a params value that I want to set and do a where query on - something like this:

```
@connections = current_user.all_connections.where(request_status: params[:request_status])
```

`current_user.all_connections` returns an AR object (aka...it is also a query method with a where call).

The issue I am facing is that right now, the above query returns an empty collection. The reason I believe is that per the [API docs in Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

> Where conditions on an enum attribute must use the ordinal value of an
>   enum.

Given that `params[:request_status]` will look like this:

```
Parameters: {"request_status"=>"accepted"}
```

How would I modify that `where` query to reflect this? I know one other option is just to modify the parameter to be the ordinal value, rather than the string, but I am curious how I might achieve this with the string value rather than the ordinal value?

**Edit 1**

Here are the server logs:

```
Started GET "/connections?request_status=accepted" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-04 20:23:08 -0500
Processing by ConnectionsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"request_status"=>"accepted"}
  User Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 3]]
  Connection Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE "connections"."invited_user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "connections"."created_at" DESC  [["invited_user_id", 3]]
  Connection Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE "connections"."inviter_user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "connections"."created_at" DESC  [["inviter_user_id", 3]]
  Connection Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE (connections.invited_user_id = 3 OR connections.inviter_user_id = 3) AND "connections"."request_status" = 0  ORDER BY "connections"."created_at" DESC
  Rendered connections/index.html.erb within layouts/connections (0.3ms)
  Rendered connections/_header.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (61.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (1142.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1184ms (Views: 1155.5ms | ActiveRecord: 10.4ms)
```

**Edit 2**

This is the index action for that controller.

```
  def index
    params[:request_status] = "pending" if params[:request_status].nil?
    @connections = current_user.all_connections.where(request_status: params[:request_status]).order(created_at: :desc).group_by { |c| c.created_at.to_date }
  end
```

What's strange is that for every action that I click on that should send the correct `request_status` it still sends the SQL with `request_status = 0`.

I commented out the `params[:request_status] =` setter in the controller to see if that was doing it, but it wasn't it.

What could be causing this issue?

Here is another log for a different status:

```
Started GET "/connections?request_status=rejected" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-04 21:30:29 -0500
Processing by ConnectionsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"request_status"=>"rejected"}
  User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 3]]
  Connection Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE "connections"."invited_user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "connections"."created_at" DESC  [["invited_user_id", 3]]
  Connection Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE "connections"."inviter_user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "connections"."created_at" DESC  [["inviter_user_id", 3]]
  Connection Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE (connections.invited_user_id = 3 OR connections.inviter_user_id = 3) AND "connections"."request_status" = 0  ORDER BY "connections"."created_at" DESC
  Rendered connections/index.html.erb within layouts/connections (0.2ms)
  Rendered connections/_header.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (60.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (1103.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1130ms (Views: 1112.5ms | ActiveRecord: 7.3ms)
```

Comment: provide SQL query logs. It works in my console with string. May be it is connected with current_user or all_connections methods.

Comment: @JoeHalfFace - Just updated the question with server logs.

Comment: `AND "connections"."request_status" = 0` - this shows that source of problem is not enum.  Probably there is no pending connection of user with id 3

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Good catch. Not sure why it is doing that. I just updated the question with more info. For what it's worth, it has that same SQL query with `request_status = 0` for all statuses (i.e. accepted, pending, etc.).

Comment: does enum have default value in DB schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Connection.request_statuses["pending"]` to get 0.

So you can use string in your query like this:

`@connections = current_user.all_connections.where(request_status: Connection.request_statuses[params[:request_status]])`